# Не получается собрать, чтобы работало может кто поможет разобраться?

Tags: c++

1. sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev
2. sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 libblas.so.3 /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so.0 41 
   --slave /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3 liblapack.so.3 /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so.0
   `$cmake .. -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0 -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done -- Detecting CXX compile features -- Detecting CXX compile features - done -- Looking for sgemm_ -- Looking for sgemm_ - not found -- Looking for C++ include pthread.h -- Looking for C++ include pthread.h - found -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found -- Found Threads: TRUE -- Looking for sgemm_ -- Looking for sgemm_ - found -- Found BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblas.so -- Looking for cheev_ -- Looking for cheev_ - found -- A library with LAPACK API found. -- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda (found suitable exact version "11.0") -- Found OpenCV: /usr/local (found version "4.4.0") -- Configuring done -- Generating done -- Build files have been written to: /home/mihuzz/QTprojects/dlibFace2/build $make /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/dlibFace2.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'dgesvd_' /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread//liblapack.so.3: ошибка добавления символов: DSO missing from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dlibFace2.dir/build.make:148: dlibFace2] Ошибка 1 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/dlibFace2.dir/all] Ошибка 2 make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Ошибка 2`